# Calling SearchBox component enter event and populating data on the child component

Tags: react-native

In my application I have an header component with a SearchBox and label and I have used that component in the drawer menu for a common layout and that component is appearing as a generic search component in all of my screen.My header component is like this ..

```
    return (
          <Block style={headerStyles}>
            <NavBar
              back={back}
              title={title}
              style={styles.navbar}
              transparent={transparent}
              right={this.renderRight()}
              rightStyle={{ alignItems: "center" }}
              leftStyle={{ flex: 0.3, paddingTop: 2 }}
              leftIconName="navicon"
              leftIconColor={white ? theme.COLORS.WHITE : theme.COLORS.ICON}
              titleStyle={[
                styles.title,
                { color: theme.COLORS[white ? "WHITE" : "ICON"] }
              ]}
              onLeftPress={this.handleLeftPress}
            />
            <Input
            right
            color="black"
            style={styles.search}
            placeholder="What are you looking for?"
            iconContent={
              <Icon
                size={16}
                color={theme.COLORS.MUTED}
                name="magnifying-glass"
                family="entypo"
              />
            }
          />
          </Block>
        );
```

And inside my menu I have used it like this.

```
    const DashboardStack = createStackNavigator(
      {
        Components: {
          screen: DashboardScreen,
          navigationOptions: ({ navigation }) => ({
            header: (
              <Header
                title="Dashboard"
                navigation={navigation}
              />
            )
          })
        },
        ProductDetail: {
          screen: ProductDetailsTest
        }
      },
      {
        cardStyle: { backgroundColor: "#EEEEEE" },
        transitionConfig
      }
    );
```

Now I want to call a search functionality in my Dashboard screen how I will implement this.Any reference for that >
Thanks
Utpal Maity

Comment: are you sure this is react-native code as react-native does not have `Block` `NavBar` `Input` tags

Comment: Those are nothing but a custom component which is provided by Galio framework it is build on top of View,Text,Button component

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question correctly, you want to use Header component's search functionality in one of your screens.One of the ways you can achieve this is, render Header component in your rootApp component(where you are initialising stackNavigator ) and have a ref assigned to it. Then, you can pass this ref as screen props to stackNavigator(rootNavigator) component. With this, all screens will have access to your Header component.

Hope this solves your query.
Refer : https://reactnavigation.org/docs/en/navigation-options.html
Refer:[How screenProps can be used?](https://github.com/react-navigation/react-navigation/issues/1931) and make changes according to your requirements.

Edit: I'll try to provide an example..

1.Create your AppContainer with your AppNavigator like you have done..

```
 const ScreenStack = createAppContainer(createStackNavigator(
  {
    Components: {
      screen: DashboardScreen,

    },
    ProductDetail: {
      screen: ProductDetailsTest
    }
  },
  {
    cardStyle: { backgroundColor: "#EEEEEE" },
    transitionConfig
  }

))
```

2.Render ScreenStack in a Component called Root with your Header component with ref passed to it and pass Header component as screenProps to ScreenStack

```
class Root extends React.Component{
   ....
  render(){
     return(){
           <View style={{flex:1}}>
              <Header ref={this.header}></Header> 
              <ScreenStack
                ref={this.navigator}
                screenProps={{header: this.header }}
              />
          </View> 
        }
      } 
    }
 export default Root
```

3.Now, in your App.js render Root

```
//import Root
class App extends React.Component {
    render() {
        return (

                <Root />

        );
    }
}
```

Now, you should be able to access Header in any of the screens and use method of searching like this.props.screenProps.header.current.search()

Hope, this helps you!!

Comment: Can you provide any example on this